# Why is the field default value set during ajax request not appearing in the form

Tags: forms, ajax

I have the following in my form function

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/system/ajax' && $form_state['values']['x']) {
    $r = get_info($form_state['values']['x']);
  }

  $form['type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Type',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="type-select">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' => $type_options,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'change',
      'callback' => 'qty_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'my-form',
    ),
  );
  $form['group_a']['qty'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Quantity'),
    '#default_value' => $r['qty'],
  );

return $form;
```

My callback is:

```
function qty_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form;
}
```

Just before the form function returns the form, $form[qty][#default_value] has the correct value in it. In the callback, that value is still present. But it never appears on the form.

I have tried putting the if statement above and below the form fields, and have tried using #value.

If I put the following in the callback

```
  $form['group_a']['qty']['#value'] = $form['group_a']['qty']['#default_value'];
  return $form;
```

OR the following in the form function

```
  if (!$form_state['input']['qty']) $form_state['input']['qty'] = $r['qty'];
```

the value appears, but I don't think this is the way I'm supposed to handle it:

Comment: Not sure if it has sth to do with that, but the callback function should be `qty_callback($form, &$form_state)` (note the ampersand in front of form_state).

Comment: Correct, sorry, it was a typo. But no, I'm not altering $form_state, just returning $form, so it shouldn't matter.